# Sequelize Model - ID is null in constructor

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a class which extends Sequelize.Model, id column has all the needed attributes and it works almost fine, with the only problem, it doesn't give ID in constructor, as it have not been saved by that time in the database.

```
class Shop extends Sequelize.Model {

    constructor(a, b){
        super(a, b);
        
        console.log('SHOP 1', this);
        //here this.id = null
        
        setTimeout(() => console.log('SHOP 2', this), 3000); 
        // ^ here, this.id = real ID, because instance was inserted in db at this time
        
    }
}
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2vpq.png)

As it appears on the picture, the constructor is called as soon as I create an instance with `Shop.create({pos: ...})`, then it calls INSERT and receives id. I understand this behaviour, but is there a way to create an instance after it was inserted?

I know I could have done this: `Shop.create({pos: ...}).then(it => { it.id });` but that code wouldn't run on already created instances. They, on the other hand, have their IDs working in constructor.

So is there a better way of solving this? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Problem was solved this way:

```
class Shop extends Sequelize.Model {
super.init({
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
    }, {
        sequelize: //seq connection here,
        modelName: 'shop',
        // added a hook for new instances !!
        hooks: { afterCreate: (a) => a.prepare() }
    });
};

constructor(a, b){
    super(a, b);
    // this would be called for instances,
    // created in past and retrieved from db (so they already have ID)
    if (this.id) this.prepare(); 
}

prepare(){
    // do stuff with this.id
} }
```

Comment: Show `id` definition

Comment: It is: `id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },`

Comment: Looks good. Maybe you need to look at hooks?

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly it was solved with afterCreate hook. A workaround but it works